# Ab Nobis - to leave us

Tags: sentence-translation, example-request

A quick search can barely confirm that ablative plural *ab nobis* is found in collocation. This might literally translate German *von uns*, as in the euphemism

> **von uns** gegangen sein 
> * **from us** ygone be 
> *have passed away*

1. Is *ab nobis* grammatical for the surface reading, *they have left us*?
2. Is a similar euphemism with *nobis* or something close to it known from formal obituaries or the vernacular?

---

Disclaimer: Asking because of the uncertain etymology of vernacular German *abnippeln* "pass away, to die". Of course I am grabbing for straws and the details don't matter.

Answer (score 5):

*Ab nōbīs* literally means "from us". Thus, *discedere ab nōbīs* would literally mean "to depart from us", and we see this exact phrase in e.g. Caesar's Bellum Civile:

> **Discedere ab nobis** et novam temptare fortunam novasque amicitias experiri constituerunt.
> *They decided **to depart from us**, test their luck anew, and and try some new alliances.*

However, I'm only familiar with it being used for literal departure, not death. If this was an idiom used in epitaphs, it's not one I've seen.

Comment: I'll accept first beyond the goal post lest I be blamed of multiple questions in one and hope somebody can offer a medieval euphemism.

Comment: Note: While *discedere* is generally not used as an euphemism for dying, the similar sounding *decedere* is, and frequently; however, it is normally used absolutely and apparently never with *ab*. However, interestingly one example is *pater nobis decessit* (Cic. Att. 1, 6).

Answer (score 5):

To answer your first question, a quick search on PHI Latin Texts shows "ab nōbīs" to be attested 19 times, whereas "ā nōbīs" appears 853 times. So, while they're both grammatical, the latter seems to be far more prevalent in the corpus.

As for your second question, *discēdere, discēdō* means "to pass away" or "to disappear" in a more literal sense of going away, though it can mean "to die alone". There is, however, also the expression *ā vītā discēdere, discēdō*, but that might be confusing or clunky when you're already saying *ā/ab nōbīs*. There is a variety of expressions you can use to (euphemistically) speak of dying: plain *morī, morior* for "to die", dē/ē vītā exīre, exeō/migrāre, migrō for "to depart from life" (though *ā/ab nōbīs* might be out of place when you're already saying you're departing **from** something/someone), *obīre, obeō* for "to encounter" (as in, encounter death), etc.

Comment: "ubi hae sollicitudines discessere, Liv. 4, 52 fin.—" (Lewis & Short). Very good, thank you very much.